# Renaming file with os.rename causing NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7, rename

I'm trying to rename 2 raster files: `old_name.jpg` and `old_name.tiff` to `new_name.jpg` and `new_name.tiff`:

```
new_name = 'new_name' # defining new name here

for root_dir, dirname, filenames in os.walk(TargetDir):
    for file in filenames:

        if re.match(r'.*.jpg$', file, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:    # converting jpg
            os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, file), os.path.join(root_dir, new_name + ".jpg"))
        if re.match(r'.*.tiff$', file, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:    # converting tiff
            os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, file), os.path.join(root_dir, new_name + ".tiff"))
```

It works on jpg like charm, but then throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/!Scripts/py2/meta_to_BKA.py", line 66, in <module>
    os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, file), os.path.join(root_dir, new_name + ".tiff"))
NameError: name 'new_name' is not defined
```

Note that it uses `new_name` to rename jpg, but then variable vanishes in the very next block. I tried using `shutil.move()`, but got the same error. What is the problem?

Comment: Just a headsup: in the regex a r'.+\.jpg$' would be better

Comment: I tried to copy your exact code and run it. It perfectly worked. Are you sure you captured the most relevant part of your code? It looks like the error is somewhere else...Also did you check your indentation (tabs and spaces)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace suggests that your snippet isn't the whole story.
I can't reproduce:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import os

TargetDir = '/tmp/test'

new_name = 'new_name'


def main():
    for root_dir, _, filenames in os.walk(TargetDir):
        for filename in filenames:
            if '.' not in filename:
                continue
            endswith = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1].lower()
            if endswith not in set(['jpg', 'tiff']):
                continue
            new_filename = '{}.{}'.format(new_name, endswith)
            from_fn = os.path.join(root_dir, filename)
            to_fn = os.path.join(root_dir, new_filename)
            print ('Moving', from_fn, 'to', to_fn)
            os.rename(from_fn, to_fn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I took the liberty of rewriting a bit.

```
> python hest.py                               
Moving /tmp/test/narf.jpg to /tmp/test/new_name.jpg
Moving /tmp/test/bla.tiff to /tmp/test/new_name.tiff
```